How to get the JA3 and JA4 fingerprint from the client in nodejs?
As far as I searched on the internet I can't seem to find an accurate answer.
I tried with pcap library on node. But I think there's no documentation on how to read ClientHello record from the TLS handshake and then calculate the JA3 fingerprint.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-tls-client-hello might help. This implements JA3. JA4 is not that different and can be based on the same code which already shows how to extract the relevant information. And as for JA3/JA4 in general - the methods are well documented.

Thank you it helped. Another question, this helps me read client JA3. But what about server JA3s? I think we need JA3s to calculate JA4. Am I right?

" I think we need JA3s to calculate JA4. Am I right?" - No. JA3s is fingerprint of the server, JA4 is another fingerprint of the client (but there are various JA4* which fingerprint several other aspects of client and server - see https://github.com/FoxIO-LLC/ja4)

Thank you for the reference. Is there any library I can use in NodeJS to calculate JA3s?
